# Keep child view inside layout in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have been trying to implement a bar showing progress data with ConstraintLayout. The problem is my TextView goes out of the layout bound when the Guideline is too left or too right of the bar.

I have tried to change the constraints of the TextView from connected to the "@id/guideline" into "parent", and add horizontalBias instead, but then the TextView will become inaccurately positioned (a little shifted to right/left side depends on the yellow bar length)

Here is the image of current result:
[image]

Here is the layout code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutConstraint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="100dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".01" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textProgress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="current value" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/layoutProgress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_rounded_corner_light_grey"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textProgress" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/currentProgress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_rounded_corner_yellow"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/layoutProgress"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textProgress" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: why you are using view insread of ProgressBar ?

Comment: there is a need to create customized UI in my case, which not only needed to add text but also small arrow icon pointing the left side of the yellow bar

Comment: so you need the TextView to be moving along with gudeline? Is that it?

Comment: yes that's right, like the one illustrated in the middle of the image

Comment: so at the end it should not go beyond the parent  right?

Comment: yes, at the start and end should not go beyond parent, and in the middle should follow and centered with the right side of the yellow bar

Comment: I think it's not possible and we have to do some work around

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184309/discussion-between-abr-and-user3576118).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to keep the text "current value" centered on the end of the progress bar; however, if this placement causes the text to be cutoff on either the left side or the right, the text should be aligned to the side of the `ConstraintLayout` so that it remains entirely visible.

Your `TextView` is centered on the percentage guideline that you position programmatically between 0% and 100% (I assume.)

I suggest that you change the guideline to one based upon pixels (dp or px) and position your `TextView` that is centered on the new guideline. Instead of varying the guideline position from zero to 100%, calculated a new range:

Low end of range = 1/2 the width of `TextView` plus whatever margin.

High end of range = width of the `ConstraintLayout` - 1/2 width of the `TextView` minus whatever margin.

The margin will remain at the low end of the range while progress falls to the left of the low end. As the progress goes past the low end, the guideline will move to the right by the current location of the progress bar - the low end. The guideline will stop at the high end as progress continues on to 100%.

If you want to stick with the percentage guideline, compute the low and high ends as outlined above. You can then compute the low and high percentages based upon the width of the container.

Here is a short demo that uses a simple block for progress:

[image]

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ConstraintLayout mLayout;
    private View mProgress;
    private int mProgressPosition;
    private int mGuidelineMin;
    private int mGuidelineMax;
    private Guideline mGuideline;
    private int mIncrement;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private int mMargin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
        mGuideline = findViewById(R.id.guideline);
        mProgress = findViewById(R.id.progress);
        mMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 16,
            getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
        );

        mLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            private int mLoopCount = 100;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                int textWidth = findViewById(R.id.textView).getWidth();
                mGuidelineMin = textWidth / 2 + mMargin;
                mGuidelineMax = mLayout.getWidth() - textWidth / 2 - mMargin;
                mGuideline.setGuidelineBegin(mGuidelineMin);
                mIncrement = (mLayout.getWidth() - mProgress.getWidth()) / mLoopCount;
                mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mProgressPosition += mIncrement;
                        mProgress.setTranslationX(mProgressPosition);
                        int guidelinePosition =
                            Math.max(mGuidelineMin, mProgressPosition + mProgress.getWidth() / 2);
                        if (guidelinePosition > mGuidelineMax) {
                            guidelinePosition = mGuidelineMax;
                        }
                        mGuideline.setGuidelineBegin(guidelinePosition);
                        if (--mLoopCount > 0) {
                            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
                        }
                    }
                }, 100);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.17" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Current value"
        android:textSize="20sp"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.07999998" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="140dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change this one..

```
app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.7"
```

remove this..

```
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline"
```

and used this..

```
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
```

Comment: Yes, I have used it on the Guideline view

Comment: not quite sadly, it fix when the TextView is cropped from the left, but worsen it when the TextView is cropped from right side. Also I need to center the TextView with the yellow bar's right side (in this case, the TextView will always at the right side of yellow bar)

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutConstraint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".01" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textProgress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/currentProgress"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/currentProgress"
        tools:text="40" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/layoutProgress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        android:background="@color/grey_2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textProgress" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/currentProgress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        android:background="@color/accent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/layoutProgress"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textProgress" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry sir, it is still not quite correct, still truncated from the left side

Comment: I've tested this, let me share a screenshot with u ..and let me know you want this?

Comment: sorry sir, actually the textview will still truncated if I set the guide percent for a very low value, in assume in your screenshot works because the guide percent value is not low enough, and I also need to centered the text with the bar, which in your solution is not centered, but "to left of", I have found a trick, and will update this thread

Answer (score 0):

So keep a TextView in a ConstraintLayout within it's start and end constraints, set it's `layout_width` to `0dp` rather than `wrap_content`