# TextView pushed outside parent layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm building a timeline that looks like this

[image: Timeline]

The center circle can be moved using horizontal bias, and can be on top of the first or last circle, or anywhere in between.

It's build using a `ConstraintLayout`, and the the date belonging to the center node is centered below it using start and end of the circle as constraints.

If the center node is moved to the far right, it looks like this

[image: Timeline right]

My issue is the fact that the `TextView` have been moved outside the parent layout. Is it possible to constraint it to the center node as I have, but force it to be 1 line and always within the parent layout?

EDIT

Here's the XML. It seemed like a pretty generic question, so I didn't expect the XML would be needed.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/timeline_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/goal_chart_inner_layout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <!-- START -->
            <TextView
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:id="@+id/fast_started_datetime_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/timeline_start_node"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/timeline_start_node"
                toots:text="STARTED" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:id="@+id/timeline_start_node"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            <!-- 1 EDGE -->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/timeline_edge_padding"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/timeline_edge_padding"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/timeline_start_node"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/timeline_split_node"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/timeline_start_node"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/timeline_end_node" />


            <!-- SPLIT -->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/timeline_split_node"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.84"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/fast_goal_datetime_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/timeline_split_node"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/timeline_split_node"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/timeline_split_node"
                toots:text="GOAL - TEST - LONG" />

            <!-- 2 EDGE -->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/timeline_edge_padding"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/timeline_edge_padding"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/timeline_start_node"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/timeline_end_node"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/timeline_split_node"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/timeline_end_node" />


            <!-- END -->
            <TextView
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:id="@+id/fast_ended_datetime_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/timeline_end_node"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/timeline_end_node"
                toots:text="ENDED" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:id="@+id/timeline_end_node"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />



        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: if you would post your xml code then it will be more easy to help you :)

Comment: Provide XML of the layout and we can better assist. Most likely you are missing a constraint.

Comment: link is not opening

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53507970/6287910) is an answer to a similar problem. There might be something there to work with.

Comment: @Cheticamp Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for! I ended up giving the label the same constrains as the circle it's referencing, and giving it the same horizontal bias. This pushes the label off center by a small margin, but looks way better than before. It's not a perfect solution, and I'll definitely take a closer look at your link and try to implement it soon.

Answer (score 0):

When you move the circle change the constraints of the textview programmatically to the end of the parent layout instead:

```
ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
constraintSet.connect(R.id.your_textview,ConstraintSet.END,R.id.the_parent_layout,ConstraintSet.END,0);
constraintSet.applyTo(yourConstraintLayout);
```

check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

@lukas hansen
If you want to align the TextView to center, you could do something like this:

```
<TextView
  android:textSize="12sp"
  android:id="@+id/fast_ended_datetime_text"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
  tools:text="ENDED" />
```

Note: This will constraint the TextView to parent on both edges.
Also, assign a top_to_bottom_of one of the view above the TextView in the hierarchy.